# How to use variables as index in WeChat Mini Programs' setData function?

Tags: wechat

I like to use listenSwiper to capture swipe made in the swiper module, changing the previous and next items of the current item's style.

```
  listenSwiper: function(e) {
    var prev = 'items['+(e.detail.current-1)+'].x'
    var now = 'items['+(e.detail.current)+'].x'
    var next = 'items['+(e.detail.current+1)+'].x'
    console.log(prev)
    console.log(now)
    console.log(next)
    this.setData({
      prev:12,
      now:0,
      next:-12,
    })
  },
```

The problem is instead of recognizing `prev`, `now`, and `next` as variables, setData processed them as strings, which means it added three new keys in the existing array instead of modifying the array as such:

```
this.setData({
  'items[0].x':12,
  'items[1].x':0,
  'items[2].x':-12,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES5 or earlier, you cannot use a variable as a property name inside an object literal. Your only option is to do the following:

```
var data = {};
data[prev] = 12;
data[now] = 0;
data[next] = -12;
```

In ES6, you can use [ComputedPropertyName](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer). You can do it like this:

```
this.setData({
  [prev]: 12,
  [now]: 0,
  [next]: -12
})
```

> similar question: [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)